# Why do I get the development snapshot?

Tags: composer

I am following the instructions given on [Updating Drupal core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer) for users using the *drupal/core-recommended* package.

I have the following lines in the *composer.json* file.

```json
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
```

```json
   "require": {
     "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
     "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
     "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
   },
   
 "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9"
    },
```

Instead of Drupal 9.4.5, I get Drupal 9.5.0-dev.

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to change

```
    "require": {
         ...
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
         ...
        },
   
 "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9"
    },
```

to

```
    "require": {
         ...
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.4",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.4",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.4",
         ...
        },
   
 "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9.4"
    },
```

Comment: Had the same recently from 9.4 to 9.5-dev and couldn't find a reason why this has happened. Thank you for posting that fix.